# How to get headings like the documentclass quantumarticle

Tags: fonts, sectioning, header-footer

The open journal for quantum science has its own documentclass called quantumarticle. Further information can be found here: https://github.com/quantum-journal/quantum-journal. I would like to understand which font is used for the heading and how I can globally redefine all headings to look like the one in the picture without changing the actual font of the article and without using the documentclass itself.

[image: Screenshot of headings]

Comment: They use `\newcommand*\section{\@startsection {section}{1}{\z@}%
  {-3.5ex \@plus -1ex \@minus -.2ex}%
  {2.3ex \@plus.2ex}%
  {\normalfont\Large\sffamily}}`. They also seem to put `titlesec` on a "blacklist" (a term that one may no longer use), which his a standard tool to formal the section header.

Comment: If I try to implement this, I get the error that section is already defined. In general I have not found a good way to change heading fonts without changing the font of the text.

Comment: The issue is that I do not understand the question. If you want to replicate the quantumarticle layout, you can simply download and use the document class. If you want to replicate the layout of the section heading, you can use the `titlesec` package and set the font to `\normalfont\Large\sffamily`. However, in that case you won't be able to use the quantumarticle document class (as well as a few other classes, I believe).